# What is a "well received question"?

Tags: support, questions, badges

The [Socratic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/badges/103/socratic) badge's criteria says

> Ask a well-received question on 100 separate days, and maintain a positive question record. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Unlike most of the other badges' criteria, this seems pretty subjective and not very clear as to what a "well received question" is.  For instance, I have asked 65 questions, but according to the badge tracker only 54 of them are "well received".  **So what exactly qualifies as a "well received" question?**

Answer (score 4):

According to Meta.SE, the criteria is:

```
(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5
```

where each question can be counted more than once (i.e. a closed deleted negative question will counted as -3 total).

So any question **with a positive score (that has not been closed or deleted)** is considered well-received.

Source: [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)